# PHP not running on Apache ARM

Tags: server, apt, apache2, php, arm

I have installed ubuntu on a Beaglebone black.

```
  apache2 -v
  Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
  Server built:   2016-04-15T18:00:57

  php -v
  PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2 (cli) ( NTS )
  Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
  Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I see this is CLI version so I guess is not used for HTTP?

Following blog posts it says to install php5 but when I try this I get "no install candidate" but as I get a php version I guess this doesn't matter?

I have added the PPA via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and tried to install PHP5

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate
```

I have created a file called info.php and added the line  but when I run it it prints `<?php phpinfo() ?>` on the screen (have tried short tags as well). The file resides in `/var/www/html`.

Answer (score 0):

Although `sudo apt-get install php5` failed `sudo apt-get install php5.6` worked and now php is working.